# Text Layout Framework: change embedded fontFamily works in AIR doesn't work in WEB

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, embedded-fonts

i have a sample code, if you run it as an `AIR` `windowedApplication` it works, if you run it as a web page (`s:Application`) it doesn't.
I have AIR 3.8 and flex 4.6.0
The problem is the embedded font: in desktop application i can see the text changes in the textarea using `TLF` (`TextLayoutFormat`), in web it falls in the default font, but the font is there, since the other textarea displays it, so the problem seems to be the `TLF`.... but i can't understand what is wrong in the code.

Can anyone help me to find a solution please?
or is it a known bug that i didn't find on the web?
Many thanks in advance :-)

the following is the code for AIR desktop application, to test the problem just create a  web application for flashplayer and replace windowedApplication with aApplication in the code
(you'll need also to have TopSecret.ttf, or another ttf font changing the referenced name accordingly in the code, in the main folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextLayoutFormat;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
            protected function fontDDL_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                var txtLayFmt:TextLayoutFormat = dynamicArea.getFormatOfRange(null,
                          dynamicArea.selectionAnchorPosition,
                          dynamicArea.selectionActivePosition);
                txtLayFmt.fontFamily = fontDDL.selectedItem;
                dynamicArea.setFormatOfRange(txtLayFmt,
                          dynamicArea.selectionAnchorPosition,
                          dynamicArea.selectionActivePosition);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark;
        @namespace mx library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx;
        @font-face {
                  src: url(TopSecret.ttf);
                  fontFamily: TopSecret;
                  embedAsCFF:true;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextArea text="this is a font Arial Text" fontFamily="Arial"/>
        <s:TextArea text="this is a font TopSecret" fontFamily="TopSecret"/>
        <s:TextArea id="dynamicArea" text="select this text and change font"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="fontDDL" width="150" change="fontDDL_changeHandler(event);">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList id="fontList" source="[TopSecret, Arial, Courier New, Times, Verdana]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would point out that [TLF is a deprecated object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee-4b0db644124bbdb363d-8000.html) and should not be used specifically for its [font embedding issues](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashpro/2012/12/18/exciting-changes-to-flash-professional-in-2013/#comment-979),  you can (supposedly) circumvent the issue if you [embed both DF4 and DF3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096490/using-embedded-fonts-with-tlftextfield).